# Populating a listbox accurately in visual fox pro

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, foxpro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRBzg.png)I am having trouble populating my listbox, like, I want to populate it WHERE  active = "1" so that data with active = "1" are shown and data with active="0" are still hidden,

This list shows the catname "hey now" and "shiet" which they have the active = "0":

[image]

[image: here it is]

I want them to only display on my listbox the ones with active = 1

Comment: I didn't use any code i just simply right clicked the list box and hit builder. and i filled the list with selected fields.

Comment: Yes, that i am asking if i can use codes instead of just clicking things, i am new to fox pro, i don't know what to code to fill my list box with active are equals to 1, did you saw the pictures though?

Comment: @CharlesMay, where in VFP you use an xsd (you may rarely but irrelevant here)? Where do you right click and do Fill.GetData()? OP is talking about VFP and you probably replying in context of .Net (even there I doubt I would do it that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with a RowSourceType of 3 (SQL) and supplying the SQL needed. And you can do it either in the designer or in code, whichever you like. In design window, you use PEM sheet (Properties-Events-Methods window) to do this, not the builder (unfortunately builder doesn't have SQL option):

- Set RowSourceType to 3 (SQL statement)
- Set RowSource to:

  select CatName, CategoryId from tbl_Category where Active="1" into cursor crsMyList

That is all. When you run your form it would list the Category Names where Active="1" only (BTW if Active field is numeric then remove quotes).

And you get selected row's values simply using the crsMyList alias like:

```
selectedCategoryId = crsMyList.CategoryId
selectedCategoryName = crsMyList.CatName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this works! i am having trouble finding a simple answer in the internet. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

And as another answer, you can do this in code too and actually it is easier in code. Also you might need to do in code when your SQL is long (property window wouldn't let you enter long SQL string there, limited to 255 characters).

Below is a complete sample in code listing Customers (in samples) who are in USA:

```
Public oForm
oForm = CreateObject('MyForm')
m.oForm.Show()

Define Class myForm as Form
    Height=440
    Width=400
    DataSession=2

    Add Object lstCustomersInUSA as listbox with top=20, left=10, height=400, Width=200
    Add Object btnShowSelectedInfo as CommandButton with Top=20, Left = 220,Caption="Show Selected"

    Procedure lstCustomersInUSA.Init
       this.RowSourceType = 3
       Text to this.RowSource pretext 15 noshow
       Select Company, Contact, Cust_id
         from (_samples+'data\Customer')
         where country = 'USA'
         into cursor crsSample
         nofilter
       EndText
    EndProc

    Procedure btnShowSelectedInfo.Click
    If thisform.lstCustomersInUSA.ListIndex = 0
        MessageBox("None selectedyet")
        Return
    endif
    Local lcInfo
    Text to m.lcInfo textmerge pretext 3 noshow
       Id: << crsSample.Cust_id >>
       Company: << crsSample.Company >>
       Contact: << crsSample.Contact >>
    EndText
    MessageBox( m.lcInfo, 0+4096, 'Selected Customer', 5000)
    endproc
enddefine
```

Note: If you want to test this with a Form in designer, then assuming you added a listbox named "lstCustomersInUSA" and button named "btnShowSelectedInfo" do these:

- Double click listbox and select init method. Copy & paste the code in "Procedure lstCustomersInUSA.Init" above.
- Do the same for button and in its click method copy & paste the code from "Procedure btnShowSelectedInfo.Click" above.
  Run the form.

Comment: Have to agree, while I've used both the designer and code, I find using code gives much more flexibility especially in terms of creating the select statement and organizing how the data is displayed